# Mac OSX High Sierra still using git 2.17.1 after install of git 2.9

Tags: macos

System is an old MacBook Pro 2010 running Mac OS 10.13.6 High Sierra

I downloaded the git DMG installer for git `2.19.0`.  When I tried to install the pkg from the DMG first I was prompted with a security measure that preferences did not allow installing apps not from the app store.

Opening the security preferences I saw a list with the git pkg there and was able to open it in that way.  Installation was successful, but opening the terminal and running `git --version`, it still says `git version 2.17.2 (Apple-Git-112)`.

I haven't used a Mac regularly for more than 10 years, and not sure if I did something wrong, or even where git was installed on the computer.

Wondering if someone call tell me:

1) If the installer succeeded why is the default git on the terminal still the default one from this OS.
2) Where is Git Installed

Comment: Read that installer's README.txt for the install location, and then fix your $PATH to have the new git's install location ahead of the system git's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because your PATH environment variable does not include the installed executable's location, or the system location appears before the new install location in your PATH.
2. By default, the git DMG package on my system was installed to:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/git
   ```

   Take a look there. Otherwise, run the following command to locate it:

   ```
   find / -name "git"
   ```

To check and update your PATH variable:

```
echo $PATH
```

You should get something that looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If this does not include git's location, prepend the location of the git executable to your start of your PATH by adding the following to ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then start a new terminal session and check that the correct git executable is being used.

Comment: indeed, this is correct.  The README indicated I might need to rename `/usr/bin/git --> /usr/bin/git-system` but this was not permitted even with sudo... Oh well.  Also after install, /usr/local/bin was at the end of my path, rather than at the beginning